# Is this achievable via Cloud Code on Parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm just starting with Parse (developing with Corona SDK). I've had no problems with basic usage such as getting and uploading data, authenticating users etc.

I have had some trouble getting my head around Cloud Code though.

Here's what I'm after:
My *User* class has an array column called **exclude**. For each user it contains some objectId's of objects stored in another class called *questions*. On request, I would like Parse to return all *questions* whose objectId's are NOT inside current user's **exclude** array.

I could do it without cloud code, by just downloading the whole questions class content and filtering it on device, but I thought it would be more efficient to do it server-side.

So is this achievable via Cloud Code? Do you know any examples I could look at to understand how to do it?

Edit: I've tried this function. It does not return anything. (**exclude** has been changed to **doneQuestions**)

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("getQuestions", function(request, response) {

   var query = new Parse.query("Questions");

         query.notContainedIn("objectId", user["doneQuestions"]);


            query.find({
            success: function(objects) {
                console.log();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("An error occured :(");
            }
            });


});
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or just no return value? From your posted code, it looks like you're not logging anything (i.e., "console.log();" which has no args; have you tried "console.log(objects);"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the notContainedIn constraint:

```
query.notContainedIn("objectId", user["exclude"]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the original post to include the Cloud Code function I wrote. Could you have a look at it and see what is wrong with it?